# Time For SpaceX to Plot Landing Course

Tags: spacex

How much time would it take for the SpaceX engineers/astrophysicist/other employees to plot the landing course for the reusable first stage rocket to land exactly on a [214 by 170 meter landing pad](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https://www.nasaspaceflight.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/2014-11-24-22_45_36-SpaceXs-Autonomous-Spaceport-Drone-Ship-First-Stage-Landing-Ship-Thread-265x350.jpg&imgrefurl=https://www.nasaspaceflight.com/2014/11/spacex-autonomous-spaceport-drone-ship/&h=350&w=265&tbnid=yrEausEPUdVB0M:&q=spacex+ships&tbnh=186&tbnw=140&usg=__ItZwmkZpoBLx7miXCBWXMtsKqRw%3D&vet=10ahUKEwjxruujv7XcAhURfCsKHUEuBw8Q_B0IgwIwGg..i&docid=I4lTga5s7DMzVM&itg=1&client=safari&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjxruujv7XcAhURfCsKHUEuBw8Q_B0IgwIwGg) (or really any other landing pad)?

Comment: Zero, because it would be the computers doing it in real time adjusting for unpredictable variables like wind sheer and drift. Granted the launch position and the position of the landing pad would be pre-determined by similar algorithms run months in advance coming up with a good guess. Better question is how many servers they dedicate and for how long to crunching that model and all possibilities.

Comment: Sidenote: The coating on the ASDS and the landing pads for RTLS landings is radar-reflective. Therefore, the rockets sensors can 'see' it better. The primary system however is GPS.